# Flickering in final render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I'm in desperate need of help. I've been working on this for the past 2 weeks and I got to rendering.

[FNAF Movie Pizzeria - Entrance | Render N. 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-LSs1Znn9D8)

As you can see there is clearly a problem. The image does this kind of flicker thing that I do not know how to fix. If you have any suggestions please let me know. I've also attached my render settings. These are the only things I've modified.

It's my first time working on something like this, I've been using Blender for only a month now.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this is caused by noise. I suggest to decrease the *Noise Threshold* and to increase the *Max Samples*. This should improve the image fed into the Denoiser which will improve the final output as a result. It doesn't seem that all surfaces are suffering from this issue. I think the glossy surfaces need more bounces, but you may need to review the shader for the materials with rendering issues to figure out which bounces need to be increased.